# Refresh Webpage Javascript in Selenium-Webdriver (JS)

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to refresh/reload only a webpages JS without reloading the whole page using Selenium-Webdriver.  Is this possible at all?

Comment: You should explain more about what you are trying to do here.  Why are you trying to refresh a javascript?

Comment: I am web scraping, webpage is generated by JS/jQuery. I am using headless browser. Doesn't seem to update until there's a page refresh.  The webpage sometimes updates itself but not all the time

Comment: ok, you want only a portion of the DOM to update.  (so not Javascript, but the result of a Javascript method.)  You could call the method or trigger an event.  You'll need to add the markup of the content you are trying to update along with the javascript that updates it.  (Or just execute your own javascript that makes the call.. probably an "AJAX" call and a DOM update when results are returned?)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I'll give it a shot